# Event not Trackable in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to do a  tag that measures the number of times an element is clicked.

I follow the following steps to create the tag

Tag Config:

```
Track Type- Event; Category- Button Click; Action;Non-Interaction Hit- False;
```

Add Trigger:

Click on some clicks:

```
Click Text>>Click URL>> Click Path
```

I follow the complete steps, but somehow I'm not able to track the events. Please, somebody, help me to find out If somewhere I was wrong or forgot to add some steps in this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it seems that Action has no value.
If so, you should assign a value to Action because it is a mandatory parameter for events.

Comment: In preview mode of GTM the event tag is fired when you click on the element?

Comment: Sorry, But I'm new in Google Tag Manager and I read some blog to check if my event fired or not, but somehow I'm not able to find out summary and gtm click option in preview mode as well.

Comment: The information provided is not enough to help you concretely. If the event is not tracked it may depend on several factors such as that the trigger is not correct or that the property is wrong or a filter is applied to the analytics view, etc ... 
Surely the first thing I would do is to understand if the trigger fires the tag, from GTM debugging.

Comment: Today I have checked and in preview mode, the tag was fired. Maybe the problem related to analytics. The GA is not able to track this event.

Comment: GA doesn't show any real time click events or events for that matter. Even after 24 hours, I don't see any events being tracked under Behaviour -> Events.

Comment: The Property is the same? Do you have a particular filter applied to the view? In the network tab, in inspector, you can check if you have a call to 'collect' when the event is sent, have you checked?

Comment: The property is the same, still, I'm not able to track the event. Can you please check the following url to correct the mistake: https://www.travelcarma.com
Event is: Schedule a Meeting

Comment: The event seems correct, what is your analytics configuration? Do you have particular filters? I saw that there are also other events, like 'Suppliers Homepage', that is collected, do you see it in the event report?

Comment: I have filters but they are related to internal ip addresses. And yes, I have seen all the events except the mention one.

Comment: Apparently there is no explanation. If you want, give me an access to the view to verify.